# How write smart twice the "same blocks with if and return" in a function?

Tags: python

[Follow up]
Make them strings and exec them may be work.
I'm trying. -> It doesn't work because of "await" problem. life is not simple...

I am writing an function like this.

```
def func():
    [do something]
    <here>
    a = getA()
    if a > 0:
       return("abnormal exit1")
    </here>
    [do something another]
    <here>
    a = getA()
    if a > 0:
       return("abnormal exit2")
    </here>
    return("normal exit")
```

I need to write just same judgement twice because of network lag.
But I feel that writing them twice flatly isn't smart.

Is there any right way to squeeze them out like a preprocessor or a macro?
I want to Put them together out with "if and return".

Comment: Something abnormal would typically be handled with an exception. So: put the code into a method, call the method twice and `raise` an exception in case of unexpected failure.

Comment: Usually repeated code is packed into a function...

Comment: Assume that we need return please.
because the function is executed as function list and return value is listed and processed. 
like this
resp = await asyncio.gather(*exec_list)

Comment: @Tomerikoo: except that you can't return from there

Comment: If it's just a couple lines including a simple `if`, I wouldn't bother packing it into another function.

Comment: You could use a loop... Depends on what is `something` and `something another`

Comment: Put it inside a `for _ in range(2):` loop.  If you ever find you need to adjust the number of attempts made before giving up, just change the parameter to `range()`.

Comment: `for _ in range(attempts) ` would be clearer

Comment: The code before the repeated code varies, though. A loop isn't very useful here, as you are just replacing a small amount of repeated code with boiler plate to figure out what to do in each iteration.

Comment: _I need to write just same judgement twice because of network lag_ - Maybe you can share what you mean by network lag, there might be better solution e.g. if this is Selenium related and you need time for a specific element to load there are explicit waits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really look like there's much being repeated that doesn't *need* to be repeated. The only "bloat" here is the call to `getA` (which has to be repeated) and the check of its return value, which you can combine into a single line:

```
if (a := getA()) > 0:
```

Then you can write

```
def func():
    # Stuff before first call

    if (a := getA()) > 0:
       return("abnormal exit1")
    
    # Stuff before second call

    if (a := getA()) > 0:
       return("abnormal exit2")

    return("normal exit")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop with the amount of tries to allow:

```py
n = 2

def func():
    for i in range(n)
        # do something
        a = getA()
        if a > 0:
           return(f"abnormal exit{i+1}")

    return("normal exit")
```

Comment: The "do something" isn't the same in the original example, though, is it?

Comment: @chepner We don't know...

Comment: I'd wager it isn't the same because OP says `[do something]` and `[do something another]`

Comment: Well, it could still be useful to use a loop depending on the actual *something*s (as I mentioned in comments). The loop's variable might be used

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a couple lines including a simple `if`, I wouldn't bother packing it into another function.

However, if you really wanted to, you could raise an exception in an inner function and catch that exception and return `"abnormal exit"`, or return `"normal exit"` if the exception isn't caught.

```
class CustomError(Exception):
    pass

def func():
    def inner_func(msg):
        a = getA()
        if a > 0:
            raise CustomError(msg)
    
    try:
        #    [ do something]
        inner_func("abnormal exit 1")
        #    [ do something]
        inner_func("abnormal exit 2")  
    except CustomError as e:
        return e.args[0]

    return "normal exit"
```

Comment: It looks like working and it's cool. 
But is there simple any way to block them out?
This is a practical problem that I am doing now, and at the same time, 
It's a linguistic question about Python.
Maybe I just don't know.